# NGXS and LocalStorage: How to exclude certain data from local storage

Tags: local-storage, ngxs

I am using NGXS with local storage and have about 20 store objects. Most important is an object holding login information, this should be stored in the local storage. For all other objects, I would like to be able to define if they are persisted in the local storage. How can I do this?

Regards

Comment: https://ngxs.gitbook.io/ngxs/plugins/storage#usage
You can use the 'key' property to define which data to persist.

Comment: do you have a mini exampole showing this?

Comment: Works this way:NgxsStoragePluginModule.forRoot({key: 'auth'}),
Thanks eranshmil

Comment: @eranshmil is there an example?  The documentation is lacking for people new to NGXS.